# How to destroy controller in emberjs using ui slider

Tags: ember.js

Ember 1.13.9

I have a controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  centi: 0,
  milli: 0,
  milliCentiChanged: function(){
    let total = Number(this.get('centi'))*10 + Number(this.get('milli');
    this.set('content.object.measurement',total);
  }.observers('centi','milli'),
});
```

The template associated with this controller has two sliders [Ui slider ember](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-slider)

```
{{ui-slider value=centi min=0 max=100 step=1 orientation='horizontal' defaultValue=0
            tooltip='show' disabled=false handle='round' selection='before'
            tooltipPosition='top'
            changed='centiChanged'
          }}


{{ui-slider value=milli min=0 max=100 step=1 orientation='horizontal' defaultValue=0
            tooltip='show' disabled=false handle='round' selection='before'
            tooltipPosition='top'
            changed='milliChanged'
          }}
```

I see two sliders one for centi and one for milli.

after making changes to model ( complex form with many relationships). when i transition to another route and then come back to same page i see sliders a 0 positions but value of milli and centi is not destroyed.

so what I did was add override willDestroy in action of controller

```
actions: {
  willDestroy: function(){
   this.set('milli',null); 
   this.set('centi',null);
  }
}
```

The problem with this willDestroy hook is CONTROLLER is that the observers gets fired and I end up with value 0/garbage in my model "mesurement property.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if `centi` and `milli` aren't `null`'s before setting value of `measurement` property:

```
milliCentiChanged: Ember.observer('centi', 'milli', function() {
    const { centi, milli } = this.getProperties('centi', 'milli');
    if (centi === null || milli === null) {
        return;
    }
    let total = Number(centi) * 10 + Number(milli);
    this.set('content.object.measurement', total);
}),
```

Comment: Thanks. is this the right emberway. I cannot point you to the doc location ( I searched not able to find now)  but for  willDestroy observers should not fire by default.

Comment: I don't feel competent to answer question from your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). I am still learning its really helpful

Comment: For some weird reason on returning to route milli centi take value of 5